# Searching for a Corresponding Value in a TList Delphi7

Tags: delphi-7, tlist

I have a `TList` which I populate dynamically, from the database, it contains an ID and Name.

What I need to know is how to search for a certain Name in that `TList` by providing an ID without using `for` loop.

Comment: You want to search, but you rule out actually inspecting each value of the collection? How are you going to search without inspecting what is in the list? Perhaps what you mean is that you want to know how to write a DB query to perform the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without using `for` loop

Unfortunately, that is exactly what you must use. A `TList` containing pointers only knows how to search for pointers, nothing else.  To do what you are wanting, you must loop through the list dereferencing the pointers manually in order to compare their field values.

For example:

```
type
  TDatabaseRecord = class
  public
    ID: Integer;
    Name: String;
  end;

function FindNameByID(ID: Integer): String;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for I := 0 to MyList.Count-1 do
  begin
    if TDatabaseRecord(MyList[I]).ID = ID then
    begin
      Result := TDatabaseRecord(MyList[I]).Name;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for your comments, i just sticked to using loops, it doesn't affect the speed that much anyways :)